# How to fit multiple interaction models in a loop?

Tags: r, model, glm, model-fitting

Lets say i have 3 response variables A,C and M and i want to fit a model for all possible models ie fit Y ~ A, Y ~ C, Y ~ M, Y ~ A * C, Y ~ A * M, Y ~ C * M, etc. Is there a quick way to do this without manually specifiying the interactions each time?

i do not want to write

```
M1 = glm(Y ~ A , data = subs, family = "poisson")
M2 = glm(Y ~ C , data = subs, family = "poisson")
M3 = glm(Y ~ M , data = subs, family = "poisson")
M4 = glm(Y ~ A*C , data = subs, family = "poisson")
...
```

In reality i have more than 3 variables and would like some sort of loop, is this even possible.
Thanks

Comment: All possible 2nd order interactions? or do you also want A * C * M?

Comment: There's several packages for this sort of data dredging: `leaps`, `bestglm`, `glmulti` have functions for this, I believe.

Comment: all orders of AC, AM, CM and below are fine

Comment: I think you misunderstood @BrianLang question.  `AC` is not a valid right hand side.  Do you want `A + C` (no interaction term) or `A * C` the order of the variables on the RHS do not matter.

Comment: sorry yeah i would like A * C and below, so A * C, A+C, A, C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sort of functional programming approach.
You create your data, and as long as your `Y` is the first column, this code would take all the rest of the variables (no matter how many) and construct models on their combinations.

Finally, since you've done it in this framework, you can call broom's `tidy` and `confint_tidy` to extract the results into an easy to filter dataset.

```
DF <- data_frame(Y = rpois(100, 5),
           A = rnorm(100),
           C = rnorm(100),
           M = rnorm(100))

formula_frame <- bind_rows(data_frame(V1 = names(DF[,-1])),
                           as_data_frame(t(combn(names(DF[,-1]),2)))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(formula_text = paste0("Y ~", if_else(is.na(V2),
                                              V1, 
                                              paste(V1,V2, sep = "*"))), 
         formula_obj = list(as.formula(formula_text))) %>%
  ungroup()

formula_frame %>% 
mutate(fits = map(formula_obj, ~glm(.x, family = "poisson", data = DF) %>%
(function(X)bind_cols(broom::tidy(X),broom::confint_tidy((X)))))) %>%
 unnest(fits) %>%
 select(-formula_obj)
```

```
# A tibble: 18 x 10
   V1    V2    formula_text term        estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
   <chr> <chr> <chr>        <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 A     NA    Y ~A         (Intercept)  1.63       0.0443    36.8   6.92e-297   1.54      1.72  
 2 A     NA    Y ~A         A            0.0268     0.0444     0.602 5.47e-  1  -0.0603    0.114 
 3 C     NA    Y ~C         (Intercept)  1.63       0.0443    36.8   5.52e-296   1.54      1.72  
 4 C     NA    Y ~C         C            0.0326     0.0466     0.699 4.84e-  1  -0.0587    0.124 
 5 M     NA    Y ~M         (Intercept)  1.63       0.0454    35.8   1.21e-280   1.53      1.71  
 6 M     NA    Y ~M         M           -0.0291     0.0460    -0.634 5.26e-  1  -0.119     0.0615
 7 A     C     Y ~A*C       (Intercept)  1.62       0.0446    36.4   5.64e-290   1.54      1.71  
 8 A     C     Y ~A*C       A            0.00814    0.0459     0.178 8.59e-  1  -0.0816    0.0982
 9 A     C     Y ~A*C       C            0.0410     0.0482     0.850 3.96e-  1  -0.0532    0.136 
10 A     C     Y ~A*C       A:C          0.0650     0.0474     1.37  1.70e-  1  -0.0270    0.158 
11 A     M     Y ~A*M       (Intercept)  1.62       0.0458    35.5   1.21e-275   1.53      1.71  
12 A     M     Y ~A*M       A            0.0232     0.0451     0.514 6.07e-  1  -0.0653    0.112 
13 A     M     Y ~A*M       M           -0.0260     0.0464    -0.561 5.75e-  1  -0.116     0.0655
14 A     M     Y ~A*M       A:M         -0.00498    0.0480    -0.104 9.17e-  1  -0.0992    0.0887
15 C     M     Y ~C*M       (Intercept)  1.60       0.0472    34.0   1.09e-253   1.51      1.70  
16 C     M     Y ~C*M       C            0.0702     0.0506     1.39  1.65e-  1  -0.0291    0.169 
17 C     M     Y ~C*M       M           -0.0333     0.0479    -0.695 4.87e-  1  -0.127     0.0611
18 C     M     Y ~C*M       C:M          0.0652     0.0377     1.73  8.39e-  2  -0.0102    0.138
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
glmulti::glmulti(
  Y = "Y", 
  xr = c("A", "C", "M"),
  data = subs,
  filename = "my_results",
  family = "poisson"
)
```

It will create a text file `my_results.txt` with information about each of the models.

You can do it as a one-liner with other packages as well, `leaps`, `bestglm`, probably others.

Answer (score 2):

Putting all RHS variables in a `v`ector and using `combn` to get combinations of one and two (with `lapply`). The formulae we get with `reformulate` and `paste` which collapses with `*`. After `combn` we need another `lapply` to loop over the combinations.

```
v <- c("X1", "X2", "X3")
res <- lapply(1:2, function(n) {
  .env <- environment()
  cb <- combn(c("X1", "X2", "X3"), n, function(x) paste(x, collapse=" * "))
  lapply(cb, function(cb) lm(reformulate(cb, "y", env=.env), dat))
})
```

#### Result

```
res
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X1  
#       -0.3433       0.3382  
# 
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X2  
#      0.008104     1.017076  
# 
# 
# [[1]][[3]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X3  
#       0.02774      1.04382  
# 
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X1           X2        X1:X2  
#        -0.577        1.408        1.157        0.296  
# 
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X1           X3        X1:X3  
#        0.7378      -0.6141       1.3707      -1.1076  
# 
# 
# [[2]][[3]]
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = reformulate(cb, "y", env = .env), data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)           X2           X3        X2:X3  
#      0.257141     1.148571     1.290523    -0.009836
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 1.51152199743894, 
-0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704, -0.062714099052421), X2 = c(1.30486965422349, 
2.28664539270111, -1.38886070111234, -0.278788766817371, -0.133321336393658, 
0.635950398070074, -0.284252921416072, -2.65645542090478, -2.44046692857552, 
1.32011334573019), X3 = c(-0.306638594078475, -1.78130843398, 
-0.171917355759621, 1.2146746991726, 1.89519346126497, -0.4304691316062, 
-0.25726938276893, -1.76316308519478, 0.460097354831271, -0.639994875960119
), y = c(2.8246396305329, 0.645476124553837, -0.162546123564699, 
0.959822161909057, 2.67109557131028, -1.61765192870095, 0.185540684874441, 
-5.36518513868917, -2.37615350981384, 0.653526977609908)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```