# Generate a regression formula from columns

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to generate a model for auto analysis of variables and their interactions using negative binomial regression. I have made some progress (mainly thanks to SO :-) and now I would like to generate the regression string to pass onto a neg bin model and the stepaic function.

Any thought?

This is my code

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df<- nycflights13::weather
interactions <- c("hour","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
target_col<- "temp"
out <- combn(interactions, 2, function(x) df %>%
               dplyr::select(x) %>%
               transmute(!! str_c(x, collapse="_"):= reduce(., `*`)),
             simplify = FALSE) %>% 
  bind_cols %>% 
  bind_cols(df, .)

target_formula<- target_col ~ interactions + combinations
model <- glm.nb(target_formula, data=df)
model<- stepaic(model)
```

Comment: your goal is to write a formula? what is `combinations`? How is it generated? Also, you're missing `library(MASS)` or at least `MASS::gml.nb`

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/a/64104445/6574038

Comment: why don't you do it this way: `target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ (%s)^2", target_col, paste(interactions, collapse = " + ")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you have 5 variables that you want to use in your formula. And you also want to include the interactions.

So why don't you try this way:

```
df <- nycflights13::weather
interactions <- c("hour","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
target_col <- "temp"
target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ (%s)^2", 
                             target_col, 
                             paste(interactions, collapse = " + ")))
model <- MASS::glm.nb(target_formula, data = df)
model <- MASS::stepAIC(model)
```

---

EDIT

If you want to calculate the interaction just for some variables, you can do as follow:

```
df<- nycflights13::weather
vars <- c("hour","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed", 
          "wind_dir:wind_speed", "dewp:humid")
target_col <- "temp"
target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s", 
                                     target_col, 
                                     paste(vars, collapse = " + ")))
model <- MASS::glm.nb(target_formula, data = df)
model <- MASS::stepAIC(model)
```

Just add them to `vars` by writing in a format like `var1:var2`.

---

EDIT 2

If you need *all* the interactions between just some variables, you can proceed as follow:

```
df<- nycflights13::weather
singles <- c("hour","dewp")
interactions <- c("humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
target_col <- "temp"

target_formula <- as.formula(sprintf("%s ~  %s + (%s)^2", 
                                     target_col, 
                                     paste(singles, collapse = " + "),
                                     paste(interactions, collapse = " + ")))
model <- MASS::glm.nb(target_formula, data = df)
model <- MASS::stepAIC(model)
```

The problem is that you will get all the interactions: if, for instance, you do not want `humid:wind_dir`, this solution is not what you are looking for.

If you want only specific interactions, you need to use the previous edit.

If you want to use most of the interaction except some, there are other ways, but if you have specific rules, we can think of something efficient.

For example, something like this:

```
setdiff(combn(c("humid","wind_dir","wind_speed"), 2, paste, collapse = ":"), "humid:wind_dir")
#> [1] "humid:wind_speed"    "wind_dir:wind_speed"
```

Comment: Hi this worked brilliantly. Now I want to use these 5 variables but only include some of them in the interaction. How can i do that?

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to auto generate it from two lists? I have many many variables

Comment: It depends.. you can split vars in two vectors.. one vector with variables you can add singularly and the other one that you can make interactions between all of the variables. The problem is that if you don’t need all the interactions between the variables in the second vector you’ll have a problem again... do you have some sort of rules to define the interactions?

Comment: I believe it's a simple cartesian join, we should calculate vector1 , vector2 , and vector1*vecror2 (but not vector2*vector2 etc)

Comment: Thanks! also works brilliantly. Do you know if there is any way to make STEPAIC consider only significant interactions ? academy's views on models differ a bit from the industry, leading to demands like this

Answer (score 2):

Use `reformulate` to create the formula without interactions and then `update` it to include the interactions:

```
rhs_vars <- c("hour","dewp","humid","wind_dir","wind_speed")
target <- "temp"

update(reformulate(rhs_vars, target), . ~ (.)^2)
```

giving this formula object:

```
temp ~ hour + dewp + humid + wind_dir + wind_speed + hour:dewp + 
    hour:humid + hour:wind_dir + hour:wind_speed + dewp:humid + 
    dewp:wind_dir + dewp:wind_speed + humid:wind_dir + humid:wind_speed + 
    wind_dir:wind_speed
```

Comment: This looks good.. Now all i have to do is extract the colums from this string as a column list. `count_new ~ sno + spring_dummy+ cos365.4`

Comment: It is not a string. It is a formula.  If we call it `fo` then `all.vars(fo)` is a character vector of the variables in the formula, i.e. it is the same as `c(target, rhs_vars)` and `labels(terms(fo))` is  a character vector of the 15 right hand side terms in the formula.

Comment: Thanks. It seems allright but maybe I have a parnthesis problem.. I am attaching my example - 
`fo<-nested$formula[[1]]
print(fo)
print((all.vars(fo)))
> print(fo)
[1] "count_new ~ sno + winter_dummy + spring_dummy+ autumn_dummy "
> print((all.vars(fo)))
character(0)`

Comment: You will need to separate R commands with semicolon to make that legible.